# Find And Add Category to Posts

Tags: plugins, posts, categories, terms

My WordPress site is a mess. Previously, it had 80+ categories, with 1-2 sub-categories.

After creating blueprint for this site (I'm restructuring the site completely), I have new 6 categories and about 40 sub-categories.

In total I have over 85+ categories.

My next plan is to (executing it as we speak) point posts to new categories/sub-categories.

Now, as every post is different, I have to scroll to find out the right category (and untick the previously-assigned category). Assigning categories manually is a painful task.

All this is too much of work, even if I use "QUICK EDIT."

Is there a plugin that lets me search for the category (in real-time) as I type a few letters in the category box? Or a plugin that makes adding category easier?

Appreciate if you can help here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know plugin you're looking for and actually this could turn your question into off-topic.

But you can try [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/term-management-tools/).

Instead you could run some SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks! I have used that plugin before, and I intend to use it if I don't find anything else. Let's see if someone has that "ultimate" plugin I am looking for. The search function on WordPress site doesn't yield relevant results... it's quite a mess like my own site.